# Repeating while loop, until cancel

Tags: python

```
countries={'TW':'Taiwan','JP':'Japan','AUS':'Australia'}

def add_country():

    while True:
        new_short=raw_input('Country Name in short:')
        new_full=raw_input('Country Name in full:')
        countries[new_short]=new_full
        answer=raw_input('want to add more?')
        if answer in ('yes'):
            return True 
        if answer in ('no'):
            return False

    print countries

add_country()
```

I just started learning Python. Above code isn't correct, can somebody fix it for me? Basically I just want to repeat the loop once if answer is yes, or break out of the loop if answer is no. The return True/False doesn't go back to the while loop?

Comment: `if answer in ('yes')` is going to match with `'y'`, `'e'` and `'s'`, but not with `'yes'`, this is because `('yes')` is not a tuple, add a comma to get a one-element tuple: `('yes',)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `break` to break out of the while loop:
- There is no need to test if `answer` is in `('yes',)`, since the
  `while True` loop will continue looping by default:
- `answer in ('no')` is the same as `answer in 'no'`, which would only
  be True if `answer` is `'n'` or `'o'` or `'no'`. That's probably not
  what you mean. Better to use `answer == 'no'`. If you had added a comma, as in `answer in ('no',)`, then `('no',)` would be a tuple and the condition would be met if `answer` is equal to one of the items in the tuple. The comma has a lot of significance here!

---

```
def add_country():
    while True:
        new_short=raw_input('Country Name in short:')
        new_full=raw_input('Country Name in full:')
        countries[new_short]=new_full
        answer=raw_input('want to add more?')
        if answer == 'no':
            break
    print countries
```

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the while True part. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It just needs minor fixups:

```
def add_country():

    while True:
        new_short=raw_input('Country Name in short:')
        new_full=raw_input('Country Name in full:')
        countries[new_short]=new_full
        answer=raw_input('want to add more?')
        if answer == 'no':
            return False
        print countries

add_country()
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem. A return statement will break out of the function, and the OP would like to keep looping if `answer == 'yes'`.

Comment: @Wilduck The OP had more than one problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `break` command to exit the loop.

```
countries={'TW':'Taiwan','JP':'Japan','AUS':'Australia'}

def add_country():

    while True:
        new_short=raw_input('Country Name in short:')
        new_full=raw_input('Country Name in full:')
        countries[new_short]=new_full
        answer=raw_input('want to add more?')
        if answer in ('yes'):
            answer = True
            break
        if answer in ('no'):
            answer = False
            break
        print countries        
        return answer


add_country()
```

Comment: Why not loop on the condition `answer`? Then there's no need for `break`.

Comment: @Wilduck In his example he was `return`ing from each case.  I agree, it makes no sense, but the intent of his code as stated in the question is to return on either condition, with the state of that condition.

Comment: Op said "The return True/False doesn't go back to the while loop?" I think he is confused as to what `return` means. It seems like he thought it would return to the start of the loop (not return from the function). I'm pretty sure his intent was to keep adding to the list until the user answer "no" then return.

Comment: @Wilduck -- the OP has a lot of problems in his question.  I guess he's trying to keep the loop running at all times?  "The return True/False doesn't go back into the while loop" upon deeper examination looks like he wants BOTH conditions to return him to the while loop, which makes no logical sense either!

Comment: Yes it does, `answer in ('yes')` is equivalent to `answer in 'yes'`, which will be true if `answer == 'y' or answer == 'e' or answer == 's'`.  This needs to be changed to `answer == 'yes'` or `answer in ('yes',)` (note the comma, which makes it a tuple).

Comment: @tkone As far as I can tell, he wants to loop, adding values to the dictionary, until the user responds 'no' at which point he wants to print the dictionary. A simple `while` loop conditioned on the answer seems like exactly what he wants.

Comment: @Wilduck please use a comment to suggest such meaning changing edits, instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: lol, thanks for the help everyone. basically, i just want to keep repeating the loop until i answer 'no'. Maybe my way to write the code is completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the loop instead of returning the function.

It will be something like:

```
if answer == 'yes':
    break
if answer == 'no':
    pass
    # do nothing
```

You don't need the `if answer == 'no'` part. The `return` statement will take your execution out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`return` terminates the function. To stop the loop, use `break`.

```
countries={'TW':'Taiwan','JP':'Japan','AUS':'Australia'}

def add_country():

    while True:
        new_short=raw_input('Country Name in short:')
        new_full=raw_input('Country Name in full:')
        countries[new_short]=new_full
        answer=raw_input('want to add more?')
        if answer != 'yes':
            break

    print countries

add_country()
```

Notice how I've also changed `answer in ('no')` since that didn't do what you expected (it checked whether `answer` was either `'n'` or `'o'`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `return` until the answer is 'no'.  Return will conclude the execution of the function.  You want to `continue` the loop.